# Local Storage form in HTML5

Tags: javascript, forms, html, local-storage, shopping-cart

I'm trying to store numbers into local storage for a type website with a type of shopping cart... I found examples where storing text/email works but when I try to store as numbers instead of text or change the form names it doesn't seem to work.

This is my form I made on the site to capture the data, followed by the javascript that should fill in saved data from another session, capture data, and (currently reset on submit) data.

```
<form id="localStorageCart" method="post" action="">
  <label>Rooster:</label>
  <input type="number" name="roosterQ" id="roosterQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Cow:</label>
  <input type="number" name="cowQ" id="cowQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Cat:</label>
  <input type="number" name="catQ" id="catQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Sheep:</label>
  <input type="number" name="sheepQ" id="sheepQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Dumpster:</label>
  <input type="number" name="dumpsterQ" id="dumpsterQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Dog:</label>
  <input type="number" name="dogQ" id="dogQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>


  <label>Horse:</label>
  <input type="number" name="horseQ" id="horseQ" class="stored" min="0" max="99" step="1" value ="0" /><br>



    <input type="submit" class="submitOrder" value="Submit" />
</form><br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() { /* checks for stored data and fills in... */
        if (localStorage["roosterQ"]) {
            $('#roosterQ').val(localStorage["roosterQ"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["cowQ"]) {
            $('#cowQ').val(localStorage["cowQ"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["catQ"]) {
            $('#catQ').val(localStorage["catQ"]);
        }
         if (localStorage["sheepQ"]) {
            $('#sheepQ').val(localStorage["sheepQ"]);
        }
         if (localStorage["dumpsterQ"]) {
            $('#dumpsterQ').val(localStorage["dumpsterQ"]);
        }
         if (localStorage["dogQ"]) {
            $('#dogQ').val(localStorage["dogQ"]);
        }
         if (localStorage["horseQ"]) {
            $('#horseQ').val(localStorage["horseQ"]);
        }
    }
    init();
});

$('.stored').keyup(function () { /* keyup runs when key is pressed in a form with "stored"... Write to LS */
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

$('#localStorageCart').submit(function() { /* currently resets all LS data*/
    localStorage.clear();
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what? It doesn't seem to be doing anything. I don't notice any kind of feedback. I don't really have any more information to give other than that's my code and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. 

This is a lot of new things for me.

Answer (score 1):

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) can only hold strings, therefore if you want to store numbers you need to type convert

```
var num = 1.5, str;

// Number to string, would be done implicitly by localStorage
str = num.toString();

// String to number
num = +str; // note nothing infront of the + sign.
// OR
// num = window.parseFloat(str,10); // or parseInt if you want integers

console.log(num, str);
// 1.5 "1.5"
```

---

> or change the form names it doesn't seem to work

Are you updating your `init`, too? To avoid having to do this in the future, it should loop over `.stored` rather than get each individually by *id*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! Looks like all I had to do then was add ".toString()" for it to become 

    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val().toString();

Comment: This shouldn't've fixed your exact problem as I looked over your code after saying it and you're not actually doing anything with the numbers other than setting values on `HTMLInputElement`s.

Comment: I didn't update init but I'll do that. A loop might've been smarter but I like to do things this way the first time when I'm trying to figure things out. 

It looked like the numbers were staying on the page after refreshing is what i originally meant. Normally I'd refresh and everything would be set back to 0... Testing this because I want to have a totals page next. 

I figured on the totals page, I could do quantity * static price, so cowQ (cow quantity) may be 6*$100.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do it via localstorage, you might want to check json.stringify before storing the variables

```
var obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

---

What do you intent to do anyway? are you just trying to retain the field for next use or reload of page?

if so, you might want to try this plugin, Sisyphus
http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/

Comment: I'm trying to store a quantity for each variable to use on another page. So as a shopping cart, picking a quantity of 6 cows will carry over to a total page to show a total of (6)*$100 = $600

Comment: any reason why you cant just use the SESSION if this is coded in PHP? in my humble opinion, using localstorage for this might be a bit overkill

Comment: but if you still want to do it via localstorage, you might want to check json.stringify before storing the variables